# Check for runs of duplicated characters in a String

Tags: java

I'm trying to check for when someone inputs a message into chat that duplicates a character too many times. I want to do this for all possible characters and check if they're over a certain limit.

```
int WithChars = m.length();
int WithoutChars = m.replace("-", "").length();


if(WithChars - WithoutChars >= 10) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

At the moment it only checks for '-' but I want it to check for multiple characters, so if someone typed "<<<<<<<<" or "aaaaaa" it'd still do this check.

Comment: Do what check? I don't get what you're trying to do. a string without characters is an empty string.

Comment: Are you looking for 10 (or more) repeated characters in a row?

Comment: @Andreas He/she wants to check for 10 repeated characters

Comment: Multiple characters (e.g. `abc`) and repeated characters (e.g. `aaa`) are so not the same thing. Question needs to be clarified, including whether the repeated characters need to be consecutive (e.g. is `aaabaaa` six repeats of `a`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for regular expressions!

Using [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), you can search for repeated characters easily.

The regular expression is`(.)\1{9,}`. This is simply: match any character, capture it and then match that captured character 9 or more times (the tenth character is the first one that you captured. If you're new to regular expressions, take some time to follow one of the many, many tutorials out there explaining how they work.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public boolean containsRepeatedCharacters(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1{9,}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    return m.find();
}
```

Comment: This (for me at least) returns false no matter what you input

Comment: Use `find()`, not `match()`, and solution only works if you're looking for *consecutive* repeated characters.

Comment: @Andreas, yup. That's what I inferred the OP wanted, since they weren't really explicit, but their examples were exclusively consecutive.

Comment: @Itz, forgot to escape the backslash. Sorry

Comment: Dancrumb, thank you! I changed it to find() because as andreas said match() only crawls consecutive characters, and it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: Changed to use `find()` as that's the appropriate method to use.

Answer (score 1):

Of the top of my head, the most simple solution to this is to loop through all of the letters and check if the previous was the same, if so, increase an integer that keeps count of the amount a character has been repeated. As soon as a new char comes in, reset that integer. The most basic approach to this (I think) would be creating a function and then returning true as soon as the "repeated" integer hits 10 (in your case), I did it like this:

```
public boolean isRepeated(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

    char previousChar = 0;
    int repeated = 0;
    for(char c : chars) {
        if(previousChar == c) {
            repeated++;
        } else {
            repeated = 0;
        }
        if(repeated >= 10) {
            return true;
        }
        previousChar = c;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please keep in mind that if you want to check for repeating characters more  than once (if the string was "aaaaaaaaaa+192----------") you would have to use a different approach.

Comment: This only works if you're looking for *consecutive* repeated characters.

Comment: @Andreas Which he is

Comment: How do you *know*? Question doesn't even say repeated
 characters, much less consecutive. The code attempt in the question would find non-consecutive characters, so why would you *assume* that OP wants consecutive repeated characters?